# Re-writing the code for responsive Navbar from JavaScript to VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have my JavaScript code, which I am normally using for responsive Navbar (not using bootstrap), now I need to re-use it, but it has to be written in Vue. I failed in all options I tried.

Here is the JavaScript code :

```
    function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}
```

My Template :

```
<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
    <a>Intercare</a>
    <a class="active" href="/login">Your Account</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
      <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
    </a>
    <div class="search-container">
      <input type="text" :placeholder="$t('layouts.default.searchPlaceholder')" name="search" />
      <button type="submit">
        <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And CSS styling :

```
.topnav .search-container {
  float: left;
}

.topnav input[type="text"] {
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  font-size: 17px;
  border: none;
  width: 500px;
  background: #ddd;
}

.topnav .search-container button {
  float: right;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-right: 16px;
  background: #ddd;
  font-size: 17px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.topnav .search-container button:hover {
  background: #ccc;
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 4px 0.5px 10px rgb(228, 218, 218);
  background-color: white;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 35px 35px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #263e7b;
  color: white;
  float: right;
  padding-right: 25px;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child) {
    display: none;
  }
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {
    position: relative;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }

  .topnav .search-container {
    float: none;
  }
  .topnav input[type="text"],
  .topnav .search-container button {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 14px;
  }
  .topnav input[type="text"] {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
  }
}
```

This is how I normally do it, for some reason it does not work - I believe it is an issue in JavaScript / Vue code.

Comment: Can you share the Vue code that you have so far? The responsiveness of elements is usually not to do with Vue but the CSS of the application. Have you added the CSS for the `responsive` and `topnav` classes within your Vue template?

Comment: @Ollie, I updated my post.

Comment: Make sure you are familiar with how to [initialise and work with the Vue instance](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/#Declarative-Rendering). You must declare a new Vue instance and attach it to your parent div using the `el` property. Once you've done this, you can use the directives such as `:placeholder`. As for your original question regarding the responsiveness: does the CSS you provided work in a different scenario? Like I mentioned, the responsiveness will be to do with the CSS rather than a JavaScript/Vue implementation.